# Using res.location with res.render

Tags: node.js, express

I have the user submit a file using POST to `/upload`, then I want the browser to render `index.mustache` and tell the browser that the location is `/`. I attempted to do this with the following code (in multer's `onFileUploadComplete`):

```
res.location('/');
res.render('index', {options: 'whatever'});
```

It renders `index`, but the browser displays the location as `/upload`, not `/` as I desire. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Answering my own question)

I was able to solve my situation by using `res.redirect('/')` and placing my `{options: 'whatever'}` logic elsewhere.